# CakePHP: Model Associates

Tags: cakephp

I want to make sure I have the appropriate associations here. Below I've listed my models, then all associations:

- Course (contains 'student_id' field for the instructor, classroom_id for the classroom and 'course_type_id' for the course type)
- CourseType
- Classrooms
- Students
- StudentCourses (when a student signs up for a course.. it contains 'student_id' and 'course_id')

Here are the associations I have:

- Course: 'belongsTo' CourseType; 'belongsTo' Classroom; 'belongsTo' Student (the instructor); 'hasAndBelongsToMany' StudentCourse
- CourseType: 'hasMany' Course
- Classroom: 'hasMany' Course
- Student: 'hasMany' Course; 'hasAndBelongsToMany' StudentCourse

Does this look right?

Comment: It's definitely not homework. I'm having association issues and I can't figure it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall looks close, but you don't relate a model via HABTM to the join-table, you related it to the other model, and it will by default use the join-table.

Your join-table doesn't need a model unless you're doing hasMany Through, which it doesnt appear you are.  The join-table should be `courses_students`  (alphabetical order)

The relationships (as far as I can tell from your descriptions) should be this:

```
//Course
$belongsTo = array('Classroom', 'Student', 'CourseType');
$hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Student');

//Student
$hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Course');
$hasMany = array('Course');

//Classroom
$hasMany = array('Course');

//CourseType
$hasMany = array('Course');
```

Some things to think about:

- what if a course is in multiple classrooms?
- Are there any cases where someone other than a student might teach the course?
- can a course be of more than one type?
- can a course be taught by more than one student?